# ILGenerator - implementing clone method in a dynamic type

Tags: c#, reflection.emit, il

I wish to implement a clone method in a dynamic type, but the problem is I can't new up said type before I've declared typeBuilder.CreateType() - I get the exception: System.NotSupportedException : The invoked member is not supported before the type is created.

Is there a way around this?

edit:
Here's what I'm replicating with Emit. The cloning work itself is done in a protected constructor, and isn't done externally because I need to copy private members.

```
public class SomeOperatorInstance : OperatorInstance, ISomeOperatorInstance
{
    public SomeOperatorInstance() { }

    internal SomeOperatorInstance(SomeOperatorInstance source) : base(source) { }

    public override IOperatorInstance Clone()
    {
        return new SomeOperatorInstance(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're probably going to need to show some code before anyone can really help you.

Comment: No, you cant create an instance of a type which has not yet been created. but there might be a better pattern corresponding to what you wish to achieve... please clarify :)

Comment: Are you actually trying to create an an instance of that type or just emitting code that does that? In any case, more details are needed, especially a simple example code that demonstrates this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I was trying to use reflection to get the constructor. What I should have done (and what works) is that I give it the ConstructorBuilder that I've setup for the type. This allows me to have the type instantiate itself before actually Creating the type.

In short: Don't use reflection to get the constructor; use the ConstructorBuilder instead.